# Guilty of accusing someone of doing something you do

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

I want to know what it is called when some one accuses someone else of something the accuser also does. Example: If someone says that it's not ok to eat chicken but does so them self, what is that called?

Comment: The idiom: *The pot calling the kettle black* applies. So does the advice in the New Testament to remove the log/beam from your own eye before trying to remove the splinter/sawdust from someone else's. Matthew 7:3 Luke 6:41

Comment: You could call it *projecting* -- a term from psychology, understood by many laymen (but not all).

Comment: I don't think it can be a duplicate of a question asking for ***alternatives to** hypocrite*, because the answer to this question seems to ***be** hypocrite* (not milder synonyms).

Comment: [What is the word for a person who does the opposite of what he speaks?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100608/what-is-the-word-for-a-person-who-does-the-opposite-of-what-he-speaks) and [Is there a name for someone who calls someone else what he himself is?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40462/is-there-a-name-for-someone-who-calls-someone-else-what-he-himself-is)

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to what you are describing as "[hypocrisy](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hypocrisy)", and the saying that refers to this context is:

***[Practice what you preach](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/practice+what+you+preach):***

> Prov. Cliché You yourself should do the things you advise other people to do.
>
> - Dad always told us we should only watch an hour of television every day, but we all knew he didn't practice what he preached.

(McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms)

Answer (score 1):

For something softer than "hypocrite" you could call this kind of person a **poser** or **poseur**, one who strikes a pose or attitude in an affected or fashionable way but may not be genuine. See OED.

For example, "Johnny claims to be a vegetarian but he eats chicken all the time."